# ajax data is not loading after the function(html)

Tags: jquery, ajax

After displaying the value 63, datas are not listing in the datatable..if i remove the function(html), the datas will list in the datatable

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 attachmentTable1 = $('#example').DataTable({
   "ajax": {
       
       "url": "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Home?value=getreqs4",
       success: 
              function(html){
        var linkText = '63';
                  $("#contentcontainer").html(linkText);
              },
       "data": function ( json ) {
        return json;
       }
     }
 });
}
```

Comment: Try `function(data){` insted of `function(html){`

Comment: You need ajax callback function. Refer this link - https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

Comment: how to get number of rows in datatable after ajax load"ajax": {
      
   "url": "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Home?value=getreqs5",
      "data": function ( json,callback) {
          var oTable = $('#fifth').dataTable();

          // Get the length
          var count=oTable.fnGetData().length;
       return json;
      }
    }. Ajax data is successfully loaded in datatable.But the number of rows showing zero. How can i get number of rows in datatable after ajax return data?